# fsPromises.writeFile() terminates my server

Tags: node.js

I am trying to write in JSON file using fsPromises.writeFile()
every time I call it the server terminate
-this is screenshot of what happens
[code with error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBpOB.png)

```
const updateUsers = async (db,) => {
console.log(JSON.stringify(db))
try {
  let result =   fsPromises.writeFile(path,JSON.stringify(db,null,2),{encoding:'utf8'})
    return result
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
    
}
```

- after calling it nodemon restart and console this message :

> ```
> [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
> [nodemon] starting `node .\server.js`
> start
> server.js:1
> ```

Comment: Do you have nodemon setup to restart on changes, and are writing to a watched directory?

Comment: yes, and I tried to run without nodemon and the same problem ..server terminates without restarting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
const updateUsers = async (db) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(db))
    try {
      console.log(typeof JSON.stringify(db,null,2));
      let result =   await fsPromises.writeFile(path,JSON.stringify(db,null,2), {encoding: 'utf8'})
        return result
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
        
    }
```

Comment: first of all, thank you, but I tried this solution but in vain same problem

Comment: Try now I have edited the code take a look at type see if its a typeof string

Comment: this is git link   https://github.com/kamal7241/node-D3.git

Comment: I tried new code and it console string as expected

Comment: use await before fsPromise.writeFile as you are using async function

Comment: i want to return promise to consume it in server.js ... i used this method with  async and without it but same problem

Comment: try to change the path to const path = '../data/users.json'
and do console.log(path) in user service

Comment: in the same service i have readUser method with same way and it work and  they both have same path .. and if any problem in path he should throw error my problem that no errors accoured but server terminate

Comment: Have you tried it do it once. Also I have checked th pic you attached its starting because some thing is change in the project folder might be thats the issue try to assgin "path" outside the project folder.

Comment: i finally ended debug mode and everything work ,  i found out that problem was with debug mode and i don`t  know why that happens